# Cannot install pylibmc for python on Windows 7 64 bit

Tags: visual-studio, python-2.7, memcached, pylibmc

I have a Windows 7 64 bit laptop and have installed memcached, but get an error when installing pylibmc through pip:

```
pip install pylibmc
```

I get the following error:

```
PS C:\Users\ABC> pip install pylibmc
Collecting pylibmc
  Using cached pylibmc-1.5.0.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: pylibmc
  Running setup.py install for pylibmc
    Complete output from command C:\Python27\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\ABC\\a
ppdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-ecqocv\\pylibmc\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().
replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\ABC\appdata\local\temp\pip-gcnwr7-record\insta
ll-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-2.7
    creating build\lib.win32-2.7\pylibmc
    copying src\pylibmc\client.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\pylibmc
    copying src\pylibmc\consts.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\pylibmc
    copying src\pylibmc\pools.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\pylibmc
    copying src\pylibmc\test.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\pylibmc
    copying src\pylibmc\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\pylibmc
    copying src\pylibmc\__main__.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\pylibmc
    running build_ext
    building '_pylibmc' extension
    creating build\temp.win32-2.7
    creating build\temp.win32-2.7\Release
    creating build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src
    C:\Users\ABC\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD
 /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -DUSE_ZLIB -IC:\Python27\include -IC:\Python27\PC /Tcsrc/_pylibmcmodule.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-2.7\Rel
ease\src/_pylibmcmodule.obj -fno-strict-aliasing
    cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-fno-strict-aliasing'
    _pylibmcmodule.c
    c:\users\ABC\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-ecqocv\pylibmc\src\_pylibmcmodule.h(42) : fatal error C1083: Cannot o
pen include file: 'libmemcached/memcached.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Users\\ABC\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Microsoft\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bi
n\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

    ----------------------------------------
Command "C:\Python27\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\ABC\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip
-build-ecqocv\\pylibmc\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), _
_file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\ABC\appdata\local\temp\pip-gcnwr7-record\install-record.txt --single-v
ersion-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\ABC\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-ecqocv\p
ylibmc
PS C:\Users\ABC>
```

What am I doing wrong? Is it not compatible with Windows 7 64 bit? How do I fix this?

Comment: I have same problem. I downloaded that file https://launchpad.net/libmemcached/1.0/1.0.18/+download/libmemcached-1.0.18.tar.gz and get the `memcached` folder, wich has the requested file, but still don't know where to put it.

Comment: More: I've copied the `libmemcached` folder to `C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\include` and did detect it, but I got hundred of warnings and syntax error, being this the last: `fatal error C1003: error count exceeds 100; stopping compilation`

If you don't have that folder, you should install VC++ for Python.
Still not working u.u